# `python-telegram-bot` `app.run_polling()` from async function

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

All the examples I've seen, look like

```py
def main():
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(None, message))
    app.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

by I wanted

```py
async def main():
    await some_async_initialization()
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()
    app.add_handler(MessageHandler(None, message))
    app.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And I cannot get it working

Tried many approaches with `asyncio` and was getting the following errors:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.shutdown' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.initialize' was never awaited
```

or

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'asyncio_0'
```

or

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Updater.start_polling' was never awaited
```

Comment: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#running-ptb-alongside-other-asyncio-frameworks